# Reading custom document property saved in an excel through SpreadsheetGear

Tags: wpf, excel, spreadsheetgear

I'm trying to open an .xlsx file and display the contents in my SpreadsheetGear.

```
mySpreadSheetGearControl.ActiveWorkBook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(filename);
```

whereas filename is my excel file i'm trying to open. Contents gets diplayed in my spreadsheet control. 
Now I need to access the Custom Document properties that I have saved in my original Excel file through my Spreadsheetgear. Is there any way I can do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear does not yet support reading or writing Document Properties, unfortunately, so these objects will be dropped upon reading in a workbook that contains them.

I work for SpreadsheetGear and we do keep track of these sorts of requests for consideration for future implementation.  You are welcome to contact us at support@spreadsheetgear.com so that I can add your contact information to this request.